# Multiple definition error while linking: multiple definition of `typeinfo name

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors

I'm very new to c++ (my background is in python and java) and I'm trying to build the cockroachdb project on a raspberry pi. To build I ran the command  `make build -j1`.

However I am getting the error below:

```
[  0%] Linking CXX shared library lib/libgeos.so
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/geos.dir/src/noding/BasicSegmentString.cpp.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `typeinfo name for geos::noding::BasicSegmentString'; CMakeFiles/geos.dir/src/inlines.cpp.o:(.rodata+0x6c): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/geos.dir/src/noding/BasicSegmentString.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x0): multiple definition of `typeinfo for geos::noding::BasicSegmentString'; CMakeFiles/geos.dir/src/inlines.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x20): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/geos.dir/src/noding/BasicSegmentString.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro+0xc): multiple definition of `vtable for geos::noding::BasicSegmentString'; CMakeFiles/geos.dir/src/inlines.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro+0xac): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/geos.dir/build.make:4569: lib/libgeos.so.3.8.1] Error 1
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:569: CMakeFiles/geos.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:616: CMakeFiles/geos_c.dir/rule] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:418: geos_c] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:757: libgeos_inner] Error 2
```

I went to `CMakeFiles/geos.dir/build.make` and on line 4569 I see:
`$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/geos.dir/link.txt --verbose=$(VERBOSE)` but I don't really know what is wrong and what to do next to fix this.

Can someone help out a c++ beginner? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

apparently [the issue](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/ticket/993) has been around for a while. Workaround is to give -DDISABLE_GEOS_INLINE=ON as described on that page.
The respective switch is named differently on the [GEOS Website](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/wiki/BuildingOnUnixWithCMake) though, yet that seems to be outdated information and does not work.